# C++ - Implicit conversion of unsigned long long to signed long long?

Tags: c++

I'm having a rather strange warning being reported by clang-tidy 12.0.1. In the following code:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;

    const auto a = v1.begin() + v1.size();

    return 0;
}
```

I see this warning being triggered:

```
error: narrowing conversion from 'std::vector<int>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long') to signed type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>::difference_type' (aka 'long long') is implementation-defined [bugprone-narrowing-conversions,cppcoreguidelines-narrowing-conversions,-warnings-as-errors]
    const auto a = v1.begin() + v1.size();
                                ^
```

It was my understanding that when operating two integers with the same size but different signedness, the signed integer is converted to unsigned, not the other way around. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're not operating on two integers here. You're passing an unsigned integer argument for a signed integer function parameter.

Comment: @Evg I edited my question with a more minimalistic example. What function are you referring to?

Comment: signed overflow is UB

Comment: What evg is saying is you are calling "iterator::operator+(long long)" where "long long" is the difference type of the iterator. Thus your std::size_t is cast to signed long long implicitly and you get this clang tidy warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the actual types involved :

```
// Operator+ accepts difference type
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator/operator_arith
// constexpr move_iterator operator+( difference_type n ) const;

#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;

    auto a = v1.begin();
    auto d = v1.size();

    // the difference type for the iterator is a "long long"
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<long long, decltype(a)::difference_type>);

    // the type for size is not the same as the difference type
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(d), decltype(a)::difference_type>);
    
    // it is std::size_t
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(d), std::size_t>);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Understood. It's amazing how C++ can turn even the simplest tasks into complex nightmares.

Comment: If you think this is a nightmare you haven't touched initialization yet. ;) On the other hand rules are for the most parts pretty clear and can be looked up. And I think its the language where you can have very high level of abstraction, get low level control when needed and where you can get deterministic behavior (if you stay out of UB land).

Answer (score 5):

Since C++20 a simple fix is to use [`std::sszie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size):

```
const auto a = v1.begin() + std::ssize(v1);
```

Comment: Or use `v1.end()`. ;)